# XmlSerializer behaves different with a property's private getter on .net framework and .net core

Tags: c#, .net, xmlserializer

I've consumed a third party nuget package which supported .net core and .net framework (.net standard).

My project was a .net framework 4.62 project and when I've used that third party, I've received an exception from the `XmlSerializer`.

The problem was due to a private getter in a property.

> Only public properties and fields can be serialized. Properties must have public accessors (get and set methods). If you need to serialize non-public data, use the BinaryFormatter class rather than XML serialization.

[Full Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-3.0/182eeyhh(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

After receiving that error, I tried to open a .net core 2.2 project, consumed the same third party nuget and saw that the same code worked there.

He is a small example of code that reproduces the issue:

```
public class Test
{
    public string TestProp { private get; set; }
}

// Exception on .net 462 and works on .net core 2.2
var serializer = XmlSerializer.FromTypes(new[] { typeof(Test) });
```

So, is this a bug on the .net core implementation or a feature?
Is there anything I can do rather to support this on .net framework without forking the repo and fixing the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "bug" here is that it fails at a different time; on net462 it fails during `FromTypes`; on `netcoreapp2.2` and `netcoreapp3.0`, it fails during the `Serialize`, with:

> System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the XML document.
>   ---> System.MethodAccessException: Attempt by method 'Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterTest.Write2_Test(System.String, System.String, Test, Boolean, Boolean)' to access method 'Test.get_TestProp()' failed

So ... it really isn't worth worrying about, IMO. There is no real *feature* difference, by which I mean: it isn't going to *work* either way. So just... don't do that?

But: you could log it as a bug on github, and even submit a PR so that it fails earlier, if you really want.

That said: if you add:

```cs
public bool ShouldSerializeTestProp() => false;
```

then it *will actually work* on `netcoreapp2.2` and `netcoreapp3.0`, which is... nice I guess? And could even be considered a reason *not* to change the new behavior.

Comment: The third party nuget works on .netcore 2.2 since it uses the `Deserialize` method only. The example I used in my question was just for reproducing the issue. It seems like the .net framework XmlSerializer implementation loads some kind of property info cache for Serialization and Deserialization when it tries to create the Serializer for the type and the .net core implementation defers that..
Seems like I'll need to submit a PR or fork the third party to support this. Thank you.